# docker+elasticsearch: access is denied when creating the log file

Tags: linux, elasticsearch, docker, centos

I am trying to run elasticsearch (5.3.0) in a docker container like this:

```
docker run 
--network=host 
--publish 9203:9200 
--publish 9300:9300 
--env ES_JAVA_OPTS="-Xms4g -Xmx4g" 
--env "bootstrap.memory_lock=true" 
--cap-add=IPC_LOCK 
--ulimit memlock=-1:-1 --ulimit nofile=65536:65536 
--volume /etc/elasticsearch/ip-spotlight.elasticsearch.RR6.yml:/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml 
--volume /usr/ip-spotlight/elasticsearch/RR6:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data 
--volume /var/log/elasticsearch:/usr/share/elasticsearch/logs 
--label app="ip-spotlight" 
--label service="elasticsearch" 
--label func="RR6" 
--name "ip-spotlight.elasticsearch.RR6" 
docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:5.3.2
```

SElinux is disabled (in order to be completely sure):

```
# getenforce
Disabled
```

And in order to be completely sure here are the permissions of `/var/log/elasticsearch`:

```
# ls -salt /var/log/elasticsearch/
total 8
4 drwxrwxrwx.  2 elasticsearch elasticsearch 4096 May  4 15:12 .

# cat /etc/*release*
CentOS Linux release 7.3.1611 (Core) 
Derived from Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7.3 (Source)
NAME="CentOS Linux"
VERSION="7 (Core)"
ID="centos"
ID_LIKE="rhel fedora"
VERSION_ID="7"
PRETTY_NAME="CentOS Linux 7 (Core)"
ANSI_COLOR="0;31"
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:centos:centos:7"
HOME_URL="https://www.centos.org/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.centos.org/"

CENTOS_MANTISBT_PROJECT="CentOS-7"
CENTOS_MANTISBT_PROJECT_VERSION="7"
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT="centos"
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT_VERSION="7"

CentOS Linux release 7.3.1611 (Core) 
CentOS Linux release 7.3.1611 (Core) 
cpe:/o:centos:centos:7
```

And the error message getting displayed is:

```
2017-05-04 13:10:24,621 main ERROR Unable to create file /var/log/elasticsearch/ip-spotlight.elasticsearch.RR6_access.log java.io.IOException: No such file or directory
```

EDIT: adding the log file manually

```
# touch /var/log/elasticsearch/ip-spotlight.elasticsearch.RR6_access.log
# chmod 777 /var/log/elasticsearch/ip-spotlight.elasticsearch.RR6_access.log
# docker run --network=host --publish 9203:9200 --publish 9300:9300 --env ES_JAVA_OPTS="-Xms4g -Xmx4g" --env "bootstrap.memory_lock=true" --cap-add=IPC_LOCK --ulimit memlock=-1:-1 --ulimit nofile=65536:65536 --volume /etc/elasticsearch/ip-spotlight.elasticsearch.RR6.yml:/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml --volume /usr/ip-spotlight/elasticsearch/RR6:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data --volume /var/log/elasticsearch:/usr/share/elasticsearch/logs --label app="ip-spotlight" --label service="elasticsearch" --label func="RR6" --name "ip-spotlight.elasticsearch.RR6" docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:5.3.2
2017-05-04 13:10:24,621 main ERROR Unable to create file /var/log/elasticsearch/ip-spotlight.elasticsearch.RR6_access.log java.io.IOException: No such file or directory
```

EDIT: official documentations says `The container runs Elasticsearch as user elasticsearch using uid:gid 1000:1000. Bind mounted host directories and files, such as custom_elasticsearch.yml above, need to be accessible by this user.`
but on the server, having installed also elasticsearch as a service I see that:

```
$ id elasticsearch
uid=990(elasticsearch) gid=988(elasticsearch) groups=988(elasticsearch)
```

Please note that I did `chmod 777` in all related files and directories. Could you please advise on how-to resolve this ?

Answer (score 0):

While you are executing your docker run command, you are giving the name as `ip-spotlight.elasticsearch.RR6` which is not present under the /var/log/xxx directory, make sure that you have accessible or valid log file which you can use for this.

Comment: Thanks @mano I just edited my original post, could you please review and tell me if you meant sth different ?

Comment: @NikosSkalis this is a mount issue, please make sure that you have mounted it properly

Comment: please see the 2nd edit, any idea how to overcome this ?

Comment: are you running Docker in Docker? if so I just want to ask you have you started your container in privileged mode?

Comment: thanks for helping out. i am not running docker-in-docker. --privileged didn't help. i tried to run with --user 1000:1000 and having adjusted the log path to 777, but it didn't help.

Comment: if you want to run the elastic search without any customization I would highly recommend you to have a look at this link https://elk-docker.readthedocs.io/